# cocoa plugin calling webpage javascript

Tags: javascript, cocoa, plugins, safari, nsview

I have a cocoa plugin embedded on an html page. This page also defines a javascript function in the header. I'd like to programmatically call this javascript function from my plugin. This was easy enough under IE/firefox/chrome plugins. How does this work under cocoa/safari? I think the problem comes down to accessing the pages webview and getting the webScriptObject. Once I have this I can use "callWebScriptMethod" af follows:

```
[scriptObject callWebScriptMethod:@"sayHello" withArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:"@chris"]];
```

However, I don't know how to access the webview of the page hosting my plugin. My plugin is defined as "WASafariPluginView : NSView " and I don't see anything in its object hierarchy I can use to obtain the "parent" webview.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your plug-in view is instantiated, WebKit calls the `+plugInViewWithArguments:` method of your view's main class.

The arguments parameter to that method is a dictionary that you can query for various information. In your case, you want the object corresponding to the `WebPlugInContainerKey`.

This is an object conforming to the `WebPlugInContainer` informal protocol. If it is not `nil`, you can ask this object for its `-webFrame`, which returns a `WebFrame` object. You can then ask the `WebFrame` object for its `-webView`.

You can then instantiate your plug-in and store a reference to the `WebView`.

**YourPluginView.h:**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface YourPluginView : NSView <WebPlugInViewFactory>
{
    WebView* webViewIvar;
}

- (id)initWithWebView:(WebView *)aWebView;
@end
```

**YourPluginView.m:**

```
//the WebPlugInViewFactory protocol required method
+ (NSView *)plugInViewWithArguments:(NSDictionary *)arguments 
{
    WebView* containerView = [[[arguments objectForKey:WebPlugInContainerKey] webFrame] webView];
    YourPluginView* view = [[self alloc] initWithWebView:containerView];
    return view;
}

- (id)initWithWebView:(WebView *)aWebView
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        webViewIvar = [aWebView retain];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [webViewIvar release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```